# React Component with Start Rating and Drop Down

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to create a React Component. I am just wondering if anyone has the best method of getting the functionality working as shown in these screenshots:

I am in the process of creating the app, but I was just wondering if anyone had seen any libraries that I could use, to achieve the desired outcome?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  Show us what you have tried and where you are confused.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Okay, I will put up some code.

Comment: And if you are going to use images to illustrate your question, you can upload them here so people don't need to download them from other website

Comment: From your reputation, you are not new to SO, then what kind of question it is?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I am just looking for some advice on how to get the stars working like its shown in the images using react.

Comment: Either use a UI library that has this feature or develope it yourself like [this](https://codepen.io/PM9183652/pen/axaarp)

Comment: [This](https://codepen.io/benjaminreid/pen/vNVwPW) is a good example too

Comment: I have added some code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in investing some time developing it yourself, you could use some npm's libraries, but you if you want the stars to be exactly like your's example, you will have to restyle them yourself.

[react-star-ratings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-star-ratings)

or

[react-rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating) (easier to use but it lacks on a component demo)

or

[material-ui-rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-rating) (good one if you are already using the material-ui's library and want to keep all visual stuff with the same aesthetics)

But if you don't want to be dependent on other ones code, you could do as @Amir-Mousavi said, there are lot of working examples.

Comment: Thanks. I will invest some time, but as I am new to React, I may look at some libraries. I may also use Material UI for the overall design.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by breaking down the item into small components. for example, component for displaying stars and unassigned list.

```
<Item
   <Stars />
   <PriorityModal />
/>
```

[image: components]

**DEMO**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 14px 14px 14px 14px;
  border: #a4a4a4 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.description {
  flex: 2;
}

.status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.divider {
  border: grey 1px solid;
}

.stars {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.status ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* display: flex; */
}

.priority ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.priority p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.priority .icons {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.status .icons {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.priority {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #a4a4a4 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.status-para {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.settings {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const styles = {
  rated: {
    color: "#FFCE2B"
  }
};

class Star extends React.Component {
  state = {
    stars: [],
    rated: -1
  };

  onMouseEnter = index => {
    this.colorOnHover(index);
  };

  onMouseLeave = () => {
    const stars = this.state.stars.map((item, i) =>
      i <= this.state.rated ? { rated: true } : { rated: false }
    );

    this.setState({
      stars
    });
  };

  colorOnHover = index => {
    const stars = this.state.stars.map((item, i) =>
      i <= index ? { rated: true } : { rated: false }
    );

    this.setState({
      stars
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const numberOfStars = this.props.stars;
    const stars = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
      stars.push({
        rated: false
      });
    }

    this.setState({
      stars
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (prevProps.rated !== this.props.rated) {
      this.colorOnHover(this.props.rated);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const starsArray = this.state.stars || [];
    const rated = this.props.rated;
    const stars = starsArray.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={index.toString()}>
        <i
          style={item.rated ? styles.rated : null}
          onClick={() => this.props.rate(index)}
          onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseEnter(index)}
          class="fa fa-star icons"
        />
      </li>
    ));
    return (
      <div className="stars">
        <ul className="test" onMouseLeave={() => this.onMouseLeave()}>
          {stars}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RowItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showPriority: false,
    rated: -1
  };

  showPriority = () => {
    this.setState({
      showPriority: !this.state.showPriority
    });
  };

  rate = index => {
    this.setState({
      rated: index === this.state.rated ? index - 1 : index
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div class="description">
            <p>Name</p>
            <p>Order coffee beans</p>
            <hr />
            <p>Process description</p>
          </div>
          <div className="divider" />
          <div className="status">
            <p>Workers assigned</p>
            <div>12/25</div>
            <Star rate={this.rate} rated={this.state.rated} stars="3" />
            <p className="status-para">
              <i
                onClick={this.showPriority}
                class="fa fa-cog settings"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
              running
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.showPriority && (
          <div className="priority">
            <p>Set priority</p>
            <Star rate={this.rate} rated={this.state.rated} stars="3" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RowItem />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```